# Random pseudo-walk of Poisson variables

Tags: random-walks, poisson-distribution

Suppose there is a pool that can contain any non-negative number of objects. At time $t$ it contains $n_t$ objects. Time is discrete.

Before time $t+1$ two things happen, in this order:

1. Unless the pool is empty, one object is removed from it.
2. A number of objects $q \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ are added to the pool, where $0 < \lambda < 1$. $q$ is drawn from a Poisson distribution with expectation $\lambda$, independently of previous draws.

So $n_{t+1} = n_t + q - 1$, unless $n_t = 0$, in which case $n_{t+1} = n_t + q = q$.

Let $n_0 = 0$. What is the distribution of $n_T$, for any large $T$? Let's call it $n_\infty$. What is $n_\infty$'s expectation, as a function of $\lambda$?

Note that if we allow $\lambda > 1$, $n_\infty$ diverges to $+\infty$. With $\lambda < 1$, $n_\infty$ would diverge to $-\infty$ had we not prevented the pool size from becoming negative.

Comment: When you have `q\sim` in math mode and `Poisson` in text mode with no space between the foregoing MathJax code and the word `Poisson`, the result is different from what it is when you have `q\sim{}` in math mode and `Poisson` in text mode, again with no space between them, and the latter can be considered correct where the former is not for reasons that should be obvious if you try it and see.

Comment: this is a Markov chain with one reflecting barrier

Answer (score 8):

The situation given above is like a queueing process in discrete time with constant service time and Poissonian arrivals.

Call $D_t$ the number of objects added between times $t+1$. Then
$(N_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is a Markov chain governed by the i.i.d. sequence $(D_t)_{t \ge 1}$ via the relation $N_{t+1} = (N_t - 1)_+ + D_{t+1}$. Since the Poisson distribution gives a positive mass to each non-negative integer, this chain is irreducible and aperiodic.

By recursion, $N_t = N_0 + S_t + A_t$ with
$$N_t = \sum_{s=1}^t (D_s-1)\ \text{ et }\ A_t = \sum_{s=0}^{t-1}
\mathbb{1}_{[X_s=0]}.$$
The law of large numbers yields $S_t/t \to \lambda-1$ a.s.. We recover and precise what you have already noticed.

If $\lambda>1$, then $N_t \to +\infty$ a.s. and $(A_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is stationary: the chain is transient.

If $\lambda<1$, then $A_t \to +\infty$ a.s. and $\liminf A_t/t = 1-\lambda$: the chain is positively recurrent. It has a unique invariant probability measure $\pi$.

If $\lambda=1$, then $\liminf S_t = -\infty$ a.s.., so $\limsup A_t = +\infty$ a.s.., so $A_t \to +\infty$ a.s. : the chain is recurrent, actually null recurrent.

In the last two cases, the distribution of the return tile to $0$ can be computed by applying the optional stopping theorem to the martingale $(z^{S_t+t}/\varphi(z)^t)_{t \ge 0}$. Here $\varphi$ denotes the generating function of $D_1$: for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$,
$\varphi(z) = \mathbb{E}[z^{D_1}]$. In the present case $\varphi(z) = e^{\lambda(z-1)}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Let us focus on the case where $\lambda<1$. The invariant probability measure $\pi$ can be determined via its generating function $\psi$: for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, such that $|z| \le 1$,
$$\psi(z) = \sum_{k \ge 0} \pi\{k\}z^k.$$
Indeed, if $N_0$ follows the distribution $\pi$, then $N_1 = (N_0-1)_+ + D_1$ also. Thus, setting $p_n = e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n/n!$, we get
$$\pi\{n\} = p_n \pi\{0\} + \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} p_{n+1-k} \pi\{k\}$$
Thus, for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|<1$,
$$\psi(z) = \Big( \frac{\psi(z)-\pi\{0\}}{z}+ \pi\{0\} \Big) \varphi(z).$$
so
$$\psi(z) = \pi\{0\} \varphi(z) \frac{1-z}{\varphi(z)-z}.$$
Letting $z$ go to $1-$ yields $1=\pi\{0\}/(1-\lambda)$, so $\pi\{0\} = (1-\lambda)$. Hence $\psi$ is completely known.

Comment: Thanks! But for those who are not well versed in probability generating functions, could you spell out the answer better?

Comment: I added the definitons in my answer.